# Swift AudioServicesPlaySystemSound playing even if phone is set to silent?

Tags: ios, swift

So i have created a roulette app, once the user lands it plays a sound. The problem is that the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound plays even when silent mode is on. Other sounds used acknowledge if silent mode is on, so i am a little confused on why this would be going on.

This code is being called every time the animation gets triggered to land the user on a mark.

code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.systemSoundID)
```

Any idea what i can do to make it work with silent mode for all sounds?

Comment: So your problem is that your app makes sounds when silent mode in **on**? And you want to **prevent** the app from making sounds if a user's phone is in silent mode?

Comment: @Asol i figured it out, it was the method i was using. Instead of using 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSound' which technically is true in form. After switching to 'AudioServicesPlayAlarmSound' it would act as if the sound was an alarm therefore kind of 'tricking' the system into not playing the sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once i switched too

> AudioServicesPlayAlarmSound

Im assuming it acts as if the sound is an alarm, and if silent mode is on it wont play whereas the other method plays regardless

Comment: To be precise, it's called `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`.

Comment: This did not work for me.